# Meteor and Twitter REST API 1.1

Tags: api, twitter, meteor

Most of Twitter api packages for Meteor are outdated , like sewdn:twitter-api & mrt:twit ...

sewdn:twitter-api searching twitter is working unlike ' home_timeline , user_timeline ' getting this error ..

```
Exception in setInterval callback: Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.
at Object.Meteor.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:19)
at Object.Meteor.user (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:24)
TwitterApi.getOauthBindingForCurrentUser (packages/sewdn:twitter-api/lib/twitter.js:64)
```

Is there any other solution for using Twitter REST API 1.1 within meteor  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very straightforward to use the NPM package [twit](https://www.npmjs.org/package/twit) along with Arunoda's [NPM for Meteor](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) package which provides access to this from Meteor.

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

Then in the `packages.js` which will be generated in your root dir the next time you run meteor, add the entry: `"twit": "1.1.20"`

You can now add the following to any server-side file:

```
var Twit = Meteor.npmRequire('twit');
```

and you'll be able to use any of the twitter methods listed [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/twit).

**UPDATE**

Your problem is almost certainly because you're not using futures with an asynchronous method.  Here's a facsimilie of some of the code I'm using, in which I attach a method to send a tweet to the `twit` object.  Obviously, you'll need to change it if you're trying to read tweets, but the principle should be identical:

```
Twit = Meteor.npmRequire('twit'),
Future = Meteor.npmRequire('fibers/future');

function connectTwitter() {

    var twit = new Twit({
        consumer_key: *****,
        consumer_secret: *****,
        access_token: *****,
        access_token_secret: *****
    });

    twit.sendTweet = function(string) {
        var fut = new Future();
        twit.post('statuses/update', {
            status: string
        }, function(err, res) {
            fut.return({
                err: err,
                res: res
            });
        });
        return fut.wait();
    };

}
```

Comment: Well , i did try twit days ago and the data returned " undefined " !

Comment: Check the settings and so on - I've got it working fine this way.

Comment: Does it need fiber or future packages ?

Answer (score 0):

I used 'Meteor.sync' ...

```
Meteor.sync(function(done) {
    var posts = T.get('search/tweets', {
        q: 'banana since:2011-11-11',
        count: 10
    }, function (err, data, response) {
            done(data)

    })
})
```